# what does 'you are a little trying at times' means?

Tags: meaning

This phrase is from Arthur Conan Doyle book 'The valley of fear'.

Comment: In this context, "trying" means difficult to deal with - related to the "trying one's patience" construct.

Answer (score 1):

It means that person is sometimes exhausting to deal with, difficult, or aggravating. As the [Cambridge Dictionary says](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trying), the word trying can mean: "annoying and difficult" such as in the sentence "He can be trying at times."